# what's wrong with this regular expression? getting the hash part of an url

Tags: javascript, regex, url, hash

I´m trying to get the first part of a hash from a url (the part between the # and a /, a ? or the end of the string

So far now I came out with this:

```
r = /#(.*)[\?|\/|$]/

// OK
r.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash/sub')
["#hash/", "hash"]

// OK
r.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash?sub')
["#hash?", "hash"]

// WAT?
r.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash')
null
```

I was expeting to receive "hash"

I tracked down the problem to

```
/#(.*)[$]/
r2.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash')
null
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = /#(.*)[\?|\/|$]/
```

When $ appears in `[]` (character class, it's the literal "$" character, not the end of input/line.  In fact, your `[\?|\/|$]` part is equivalent to just `[?/$|]`, which matches the 4 specific characters (including pipe).

Use this instead ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dMBbX/))

```
r = /#(.+?)(\?|\/|$)/
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't supposed to write `[$]` (within a character class) unless you want to match the `$` literally and not the end of line.

```
/#(.*)$/
```

**Code**:

```
var regex = /\#(.*)$/;
regex.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash');
```

**Output**:

```
["#hash", "hash"]
```

---

```
Your regex: /#(.*)[\?|\/|$]/
  //<problem>-----^       ^-----<problem>

           | operator won't work within [], but within ()
           $ will be treated literally within  []
           .* will match as much as possible. .*? will be non-greedy
```

On making the above changes, 
you end up with `/#(.*?)(\?|\/|$)/`

Comment: don't forget I'm trying to ignore the part past "/" and "?"

Comment: @opensas Updated anyway. The regex turned out very similar to that in the accepted answer :).

Answer (score 1):

I use http://regexpal.com/ to test my regular expressions.
Your problem here is that your regular expression wants a `/`. So it don't works with `http://localhost/item.html#hash` but it works with `http://localhost/item.html#hash/`

Try this one :

```
r = /#([^\?|\/|$]*)/
```

Comment: from the comments I've received, the $ wil be matched literally inside a character class...

Comment: Yes you're right. If you don't want to match the $ character, you should put it outside of the [] part. Like that : /#([^\?|\/]*)$/

Answer (score 1):

Why Regex? Do it like this <sub>(nearly no regex)</sub>:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://localhost/item.html#hash/foo?bar';
console.log(a.hash.split(/[\/\?]/)[0]); // #hash
```

Just for the sake, if it is `node.js` you are working with:

```
var hash = require('url').parse('http://localhost/item.html#hash').hash;
```

Comment: what makes you so sure op's in a browser?

Comment: Nothing makes me sure, it's pure assumption. I like to play with the fire. Anyway, I choose Regex as the tool of choice if *nothing else* will work. So I just viewed this from another point.

Comment: don't forget I'm also trying to get rid of the part after any "/" or "?"

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `$` end-of-string marker in a character class.  You're probably better off just matching characaters that aren't `/` or `?`, like this:

```
/#([^\?\/]*)/
```

Comment: that's exactly the same solution I've found. I find it pretty simple an elegant

Answer (score 0):

I found this regular expression that seems to work

```
r = /#([^\/\?]*)/

r.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash/sub')
["#hash", "hash"]

r.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash?sub')
["#hash", "hash"]

r.exec('http://localhost/item.html#hash')
["#hash", "hash"]
```

Anyway, I still don't get why the original one isn't working